# C++ multiset with struct erase only one, fast (overload?)

Tags: c++, struct, multiset

```
struct node {
    int idx;    // each node have a unique index
    int value;  // different nodes can have same value
}

struct node_help {
    bool operator()(const node &a, const node &b) const    
    {
        return a.value < b.value;
    }
}
std::multiset<node, node_help> Nodes;
```

So far so good. Now I want to erase a specific node from the multiset. When I use this:

```
Nodes.erase(node (x, y));
```

Every node with the value y gets removed but I want only the node to be removed with the value y **and** index x.

I solved this by doing it manually:

```
for (std::multiset<node, node_comp>::iterator iter = Nodes.begin(); iter != Nodes.end(); iter++) {
    node actual_node = *iter;
    if (actual_node.idx == to_delete.idx && actual_node.value == to_delete.value) {
        Nodes.erase(iter);
    }
    return;
}
```

But this seems to have a bad performance.
I have millions of nodes to I need every speedup I can get. :)
Any ideas?

OK all fine. I've just forgot to take the lines with the log off. So after every change in the set, a log was created and saved directly to the disk. Commenting this out reduced the time from 50 seconds to 0,0x seconds. Fast enough. :)
But ty anyways for all the responses.

Comment: Are you sure that you need multiset? Maybe you need another data structure?

Comment: You need to change you `operator()` to where if there is a tie with `y` then it compares x

Comment: I think a multiset is the best way and now it's fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node_help {
    bool operator()(const node &a, const node &b) const    
    {
        return a.value <= b.value; // changes the equality check
    }
}
```

If you have C++11 you can define a lambda as follows and make it a better code. Otherwise you may need to use function object in place of lambda.

```
std::remove(std::begin(Nodes), std::end(Nodes),
             [&to_delete]( struct node & x ) 
             {
                           return ( x.idx == to_delete.idx && 
                            x.value == to_delete.value);
               }
```

Please note, to use std::remove() you have to incclude algorithm header file:

```
#include<algorithm>
```

Comment: `<=` breaks the requirements of *Compare*, using it would be undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You can somehow obtain an iterator to an element which is equal to `node (x, y)`. Then, a erase with an iterator will remove only one element.

That said, with such comparison function, you will have some trouble (in terms of complexity) finding `node (x, y)` anyway, since nodes with the same `y` and different `x` are not efficiently searchable by `x`.

One solution is to change the comparison function to order by `y` and then by `x`, and perhaps use a set instead of a multiset then.
After that, if you want an element with a specific `y`, you can use something like `Nodes.lower_bound (node (-INFINITY, y))` which has complexity O (log n).

Answer (score 0):

```
how about

    std::multiset<node, node_help> Nodes;
    Nodes.insert(node{ 1, 10 });
    Nodes.insert(node{ 2, 1 });
    Nodes.insert(node{ 3, 1 });
    Nodes.insert(node{ 4, 100 });
    cout << "before\n";
    for (const auto& n : Nodes)
    {
        cout << n.idx << " " << n.value << "\n";
    }
    auto it = Nodes.find(node{ 0,1 });
    while(it != Nodes.end())
    {
        Nodes.erase(it);
        it = Nodes.find(node{ 0,1 });
    }
    cout << "\nafter\n";
    for (const auto& n : Nodes)
    {
        cout << n.idx << " " << n.value << "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a constant factor speedup by only looking at the nodes where `y` matches

```
auto [first, last] = Nodes.equal_range(to_delete);
auto it = std::find(first, last, to_delete);
if (it != last) {
    Nodes.erase(it);
}
```

Or without C++17

```
auto range = Nodes.equal_range(to_delete);
auto it = std::find(range.first, range.second, to_delete);
if (it != range.second) {
    Nodes.erase(it);
}
```

With C++14 you could have Nodes searchable by either `node` or `int`

```
struct node {
    int idx;    // each node have a unique index
    int value;  // different nodes can have same value
};

struct node_less {
    using is_transparent = void;
    bool operator()(const node &a, const node &b) const    
    {
        return std::tie(a.value, a.key) < std::tie(b.value, b.key);
    }
    bool operator()(int a, const node &b) const    
    {
        return a < b.value;
    }
    bool operator()(const node &a, int b) const    
    {
        return a.value < b;
    }
};

std::set<node, node_less> Nodes;
Nodes.find(node{ x, y }); // single node
Nodes.equal_range(y); // all nodes that match y
```